# Uploading videos to twitpic

Tags: iphone

```
-(IBAction)pushUpload{

    NSData *media = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"]];

   NSString *urlString = @"http://api.twitpic.com/api/upload";

   NSString *key = @" ";
   NSString *message =messagetext.text;


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *username = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
NSString *password = password.text;
NSUserDefaults *prefs2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs2 setObject: password forKey:@"keyToLookupString2"];

// username part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// password part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// key part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// message part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//media part
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\".m4v\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:media]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response is:%@",returnString);
```

}

` I am trying to uplaod video file to the specified url of twit pic  which helps the user to upload their videos to twitter. When i press button video file should upload into the url which i used. but when i check,getting a response that the page you requested could not be found.Has anyone tried to upload videos to twit pic. Please give me some sample codes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some related code? How are you uploading the data? As a result you should only need the twitpic-api http://twitpic.com/api.do   , `NSURLConnection` for HTTP-Stuff and the construction-rule for encoding ` multipart/form-data`: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: @Thomas,I have included the code.please go through it.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, hi is TwitPic still working for uploading videos for twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is related to the incorrect urlString. I also dont see which twitpic-api-version you are using.

[twitpic-api-version-2](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/2/upload/) (latest api-version *this should be used*) needs authorization first via OAuth and api-key, message and media as parameters
urlString should look like: `http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.xml`

[twitpic-api-version-1](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/1/upload/) (not the latest one: only there because of compability. Will be shut down sometime in future) needs the parameters you added but also two additional oauth-parameter which are missing in your body.
urlString should look like: `http://api.twitpic.com/1/upload.xml`

Comment: twitpic-api-version-2 is using.i have changed the url string.But now getting the 401 error.Can you help me in implementing X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization headers.any sample codes available?thanks for your help

Comment: and take a look at this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/ or the google-search-result: http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter+oauth+example+iphone